# $emit event from children to parent item that is inside a v-for in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-events

let's say I got the following structure:

```
// parent template
<div v-for="item in items">
   <span>Parent</span>
   <children1>
      // inside children1, i got another children
      <children2 @on:finished="onFinished"></children2>
      <button>Click me</button>
   </children1>
</div>
```

Then in the children1 `methods` i would have something like this to listen children2:

```
methods: {
    onFinished: function () {
       // Here i would like to disable `click me` button and change its text for this particular item inside the iteration
    }
}
```

From children2 I just execute this when something finishes in there.

```
this.$emit('on:finished', true)
```

As I write in the inside of the method, I would like to be able to change with VueJS only one of the items by the $emit from its children. But I was thinking using a data property, but that would affect the entire template, what about using computed maybe? will that work? but how?

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't understand what exactly you want to do here.. Can you add some more description..

Comment: communicate from children to parent which is an item inside a v-for... i want to only modify the state of that item and not all of them.

Comment: So, let's on clicking component x which is inside a parent holder, you want to emit a event to the parent holder which updates x.

Comment: @bhaskar yes exactly

Comment: Following closely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're missing the data prop to track the disabled state of each child component. See if this example is what you're looking for, clicking the finish button for each child will disable the other button:

```js
Vue.component('child-component', {
  props: ['disabled', 'text'],
  template: `<div><button :disabled="disabled">{{ text }}</button><button @click="$emit('finished')">Finish</button></div>`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      children: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.children = Array.from(Array(10), (x,i) => {
      return {
        id: i,
        disabled: false,
        text: 'Click Me'
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    onFinished (e, i) {
      this.children[i].disabled = !this.children[i].disabled
      this.children[i].text = this.children[i].disabled ? 'Disabled' : 'Click Me'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span>Parent</span>
  <child-component :disabled="child.disabled" :text="child.text" v-for="(child, i) in children" @finished="onFinished($event, i)" :key="child.id"></child-component>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice workaround, although i just noticed my structure is different than this, i will update my post.

Comment: I've updated the answer to change the button text as well as use a listener function.

Comment: Nice, i will take a look and try to do it with my case scenario. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to properly listen to the child's emit by

```
  <div v-for="(item,index) in items">
   <span>Parent</span>
   <children :myIndex='index' @finished="onFinished"></children>
   <button>Click me</button>
  </div>
```

Notice I have also added an index to your child, which has to be accepted as a prop in your child component

```
props:[myIndex]
```

Where `onFinished()` is a method inside your parent component.

In your child component, emit like this

```
this.$emit('finished', {state: true, index: myIndex})
```

Now, you can use this index inside your method-

```
onFinished(itemState){
this.items[itemState.index].state = itemState.state
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use index of item for changing his state.

```
    data: function () {
     items: [
       {
          enabled: true  
       },
       {
          enabled: true
        }
    ]
```

For disabling function:

```
disableItem (index) {
  this.items[index].enabled = false
}
```

And in template:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items">
<span>Parent</span>
<children @on:finished="disable(index)"></children>
<button>Click me</button>
</div>
```